# Effective regex for repeated subsequences

Tags: regex

I am trying to construct a regexp where a sub-sequence is expected to occur in different scenario in the entire match. A similar example is the I/P address: For an input string `blah129.186.51.101blah`, the match is: `129.186.51.101` but the sub-sequences 129, 186, 51 and 101 each satisfy the matching condition that they fall within 0 and 255 (simplistic condition). So my regular expression ends up being something like:

```
(?:{regexp for 0 to 255}\.){3}({regexp for 0 to 255})
```

Is there a more elegant way to handle such scenarios where the regexp can have smaller fragments of regexp which can be referenced again through out the entire regexp?

Comment: logic : `([0-255]\.{4})`

Comment: It'd be easier to do the validation with something other than a regex.

Comment: @diEcho Sorry, your expression is wrong!

Comment: @Blender Of course it is, but the problem is to use regexp. Do you have a more effective regexp?

Comment: redefined : `([0-255]\.[0-255]){2}` . [`read more`](http://answers.oreilly.com/topic/318-how-to-match-ipv4-addresses-with-regular-expressions/)

Comment: With some exceptions though: http://regex101.com/r/qE1fQ9

Comment: @Passerby The problem was to come up with a more elegant regular expressions where the fragment can be captured. Your solutions works (in some cases, as you said) but still has the repetition of the fragments.

Comment: @diEcho Still does not work!

Comment: @Neel: I suggest the logic only, you can extend and manipulate by urse

Comment: proper way to do is to split with `.` and check for `0 <= num <= 255`.

Comment: @Neel, look at my edited post i have check it works for your current scenario you are having trouble with.

Comment: @NeverHopeless But it does not answer the basic question though - how can i re-use the regular expression for a fragment?

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you can try this:

```
((25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|[0-9])(?!\d)\.??){4}
```

although this will fail on a special case like `blah129.186.51.1011blah`, but i think this should be a failure match since it's not a valid ip?

Comment: this seems to work (I will do some more tests), but can you please explain how the part: (?!\d)\.??){4} would work? It seems to also recognize 11.1.1.1.11 as "11.1.1.1" , why is "1.1.1.11" not acceptable then?

Comment: +1 for the chutzpah to propose the non-greedy `\.??` (noting that the `(?!\d)` negative lookahead is crucial).

Comment: @Neel `(?!\d)` means this next char should not be a number(this compare won't consume the char), and `\.??` means the `.` should be appear 0 or 1 time, but not greedy, otherwise it will match `129.186.51.101.` in `blah129.186.51.101.blah`

Comment: Wrapped into a script: `while (<>)
{
 print "$1: $_" if m/((?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|[0-9])(?!\d)\.??){4})/;
}` that prints the matched pattern and the original data, I find Perl accepts 1.1.1.11, 11.1.1.11, 11.1.1.1.11 giving the reasonable expected result (and not including a terminal `.`).

Comment: @leonhart Again: your example: blah129.186.51.1011blah should at least parse "129.186.51.101" as the valid part of the I/P, right? I do not think it works here either... sorry.

Comment: @Neel prev regex doesn't work for `blah100.100.100.00blah` just because the [0-255] part, so you can change it to `(2[0-4]\d|25[0-5]|[01]?\d\d?)` for accept ip like `00`. but for `blah129.186.51.1011blah` it's a bit difficult, I will try it anyway

Answer (score 2):

This will solve your problem:

```
((25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|[0-9])(?!\d)\.??){4}
```

Anchored (see test results):

```
^(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|[1-9]?[0-9])\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|[1-9]?[0-9])$
```

Test results:

```
// Valid IP addresses
// 1.2.3.4
// 255.255.255.255

// Invalid IP addresses
// 1.2.3
// 1.2.3.
// .1.2.3
// 1.2.3.4.5.6.7.8 (use anchors ^ and $ to skip these if needed, since 1.2.3.4 and 5.6.7.8 will still be captured)
// 999.999.999.999 
// 299.299.299.299
// 001.002.003.004 (these use octal notation, not decimal)
```

The anchored regex will not match inside text it is only if you want a very strict match on a string that should only contain the IP

**Update:**

[Live results here](http://www.debuggex.com/r/42Sf_bR3XfTbTuhq/0)

Comment: I guess the link you mentioned (for live example) in not the one you wanted to attach. It does not contain any text.

Comment: Well my results are tested in regexbuddy, and work fine. The link i provided was just extra, i have no problems opening it with text in both the expression area and test data area :/

Comment: hmm your right, tested it in another browser and the text was gone, updated my answer to use the one you also used.

Comment: Hi there. I've pushed a hotfix to Debuggex to fix this issue. The previous link you had should work on all major browsers. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: @SergiuToarca Awesome, i changed the link back, great work on debuggex, very good for visual debugging:)

Answer (score 1):

Also, have a look at this pattern: (*Capable of matching leading zeros too*)

```
((?:(?:0?\d{1,2}|1\d{2}|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])\.){3}(?:1\d{2}|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5]|0?\d{1,2}))
```

[Live example](http://rubular.com/r/kBXPTOrELA)

**EDIT**

I have suggested a regex, but i would never recommend you to do it by using Regex. You should use `SPLIT` function and iterate over the indices and compare it with a range between 0 and 255. See my comment at the top for that.

Regarding Regex, you can prefix and suffix this pattern with `^` and `$` respectively iff you have an IP address in the string.

Comment: The leading caret and trailing dollar prevent it matching the 'blah' example in the question.  Removing those is trivial, though.  More seriously, your regex would accept 12918651101 as valid (indeed, it would treat `1291` as the match).  This is partly due to a slightly weird consequence of the way alternatives are handled.  You want the longer alternatives before the shorter.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler, Indeed it will match 1291 (in prev regex) but i believe it was not because of weired handling of alternation instead it was `\.?`, also intention behind `^` and `$` was added to pick only the valid ips along with valid subsequences. If possible everyone prefers shorter ones.  Well a good catch! thanks

Comment: @Neel, if still in trouble look at this regex too.

Comment: @NeverHopeless If you see the question, I have already mentioned that I have the correct regex for this, but notice how this regex has two similar parts - one for the first three fragments, and one for the last fragment. I was looking for a more compact solution.